# Is there any software that can transcribe MIDIs?

Tags: windows, music, midi

I'm looking for a software that has a spectrogram in the background and allows you to draw a MIDI on top of it, in Audacity I can see the notes but I can't draw over them like in AnthemScore.[image: Viewable notes in Audacity] And Sonic Visualizer is just hard to use... any recommendations? Please let me know! I think there is a word for this but English isn't my first language so please be nice if I missed something very obvious.

I feel like I need to clarify one thing: I'm trying to import a .WAV file and being able to see the spectrogram in the background while editing a midi

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what it is you want to do. You don't have to transcribe MIDI files. You can open them and view/edit the score in many different programs. Musescore is free and open source and pretty easy to use. I am just guessing, but I suspect that you would like to start with an audio file and get sheet music from it. I haven't used it, but I have seen videos on YouTube of people using Cakewalk (free but proprietary) to convert audio to midi. Cakewalk's score view is horrible, but you could then open the midi file in Musescore if you wanted a nice looking score.